# Vuetify, v-data-table headers value purpose

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

What is the purpose of the `value` property in `headers` array of objects for `v-data-table`?

In the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables) it says

```
An array of objects that each describe a header column. See the example below for a definition of all properties.

{
  text: string",
  value: string",
  align: 'left' | 'center' | 'right'",
  sortable: boolean",
  class: string[] | string",
  width: string"
}
```

But it never actually explains the purpose of it.

Does the header object just need a unique key or can I can someone use that `value` in the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define that column as `sortable: true`, it is the value, and not the text, that will be set on the pagination object.

For instance, my column is called `Created at` (text), and it's value is `created_at`. This allows me to watch the pagination object, and send the order by data directly without an extra mapping step, as my API expects the value of `orderBy` to be either `created_at` or nothing.